# How to make a sticky menu at top of browser when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, position

Hello I am trying to make the menu below a sticky menu, I want it to stick to the top of the screen when the browser scrolls down to it.  Below is the code I have so far but it is not working, can somebody please advice me where I have gone wrong.

Thank you

html

```
</div>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TREATMENTS</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Claim Kandi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Claim Kandi2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Claim Kandi3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BOOKING</a></li>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).scroll(function() { 
var y = $(document).scrollTop(), header = $("#menu"); if(y >= 300) 
{ header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"}); } else {header.css("position", "relative"); } });</script>
```

css

```
#menu {
display: inline-block;
min-width: 100%;
list-style:none;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
position: relative;
top:112px;
background-color:#666;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: "Not working"... How isn't it working? You need to give a better description of the behaviour you're getting, and the behaviour you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a jsFiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gA8e5/

I used the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a way of using this without it flickering?

Comment: If by 'flickering' you mean what I think you mean this should be better?

http://jsfiddle.net/gA8e5/1/

Comment: Thanks Rob your blooming aamazing!!! still havent got it working yet though, would this work on mobile devices too? or is that a whole new question

Comment: also where is the best place to put the javascript, i think this might be what I am doing wrong, if you wanna check it out for yourself you can at www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile, you would be such a life saver if you did. :)

Comment: Should work on mobiles okay, most mobile browsers support the 'fixed' property but they also handle scroll events differently to desktop browsers in that the scroll event is fired after the user finishes touching the screen. See the link for details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1

Comment: Seeing as you're using jQuery you can either just put the `script` tag at the bottom of the `body`, use the standard javascript `window.onload` event handler or use the jQuery `.ready()` event. 

If you do anything else there's a chance that the script will have loaded before the DOM which will render the `scroll` listener useless.

Comment: I love you, EVERYBODY VOTE THIS MAN UP!

Comment: Try to put `<br>` only until line 66 and you'll see that there's a glitch that doesn't let you to reach the bottom of the screen. I'm having this issue, related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783008/fixed-top-menu-on-scroll-doesnt-allow-to-reach-screens-bottom/33783055

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't fixed the position on your `#menu`. You have it `relative` instead. Try this:

```
#menu {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    top:112px;
    background-color:#666;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: 'position: fixed' is being added by the jQuery

Comment: He just has to put it in the CSS. It's tested.

Comment: I dont think I was clear, I want the menu to become sticky top:0px when the page is scrolled down. to begin with though it is top:100px. I do not want it to be stiuck to the top of the page to begin with, only when the page is scrolled down. TO the div, is that clearer? apologies...

Comment: Ah OK! No worries mate. I'm glad that @robjtede solved your problem :)