# Fixed top menu on scroll doesn't allow to reach screen's bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I have a strange behavior with my fixed top menu. The screen height is dynamic (depends on the number of registries retrived by the database). When the number of registries creates a scroll, but not high enough to cover up all the menu, the screen bounces and doesn't allow me to reach the bottom (the scroll jumps up again, no matter what).

I was able to simulate the behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoprzy/0kkx9tsb/

I believe the issue relies on the way I created the JS part, but when I searched about alternative solutions, almost all of them were very very similar to this one.

P.S: My screen resolution is 1650x1050, so if you have a tinier resolution, maybe you'll need to change the `.container` height value in order to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoprzy/0kkx9tsb/15/

Basically I gave up on `position: fixed` and used `position: absolute`. Then, I put the menu inside a wrapper with `position: relative` and, in `$(document).ready()` I set the wrapper's height the same as the menu. For last, I update the `top` value of the menu based on `$(window).scrollTop()` position inside `$(window).scroll()` event. Maybe it's not the most clean solution, but it solved my issue and now I'm happy. =)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `$('.content').offset().top` instead of `$('.floating-filter').offset().top`  or you can use

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.floating-filter').outerHeight(true)) {
```

So you can use

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.content').offset().top) {
        $('.floating-filter').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.floating-filter').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0kkx9tsb/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue, because the menu will be fixed on top only after the scroll reaches the `div.content` top. I need the top of the menu always visible, even if the bottom of the menu is still being displayed in the screen.

Comment: the `if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.floating-filter').outerHeight(true)) {` did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: UH OH... Sorry, @Mohamed-Yousef, but I had the issue again with a different screen size =/
Check here again: http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoprzy/0kkx9tsb/

Comment: @thiagoprzy  just use $(window).on('scroll resize', function(){  instead of .scroll(

Comment: @thiagoprzy you can use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0kkx9tsb/13/  .. this code mean .. if window width < 400   it will add cladd fixed to the div till scroll ...But if you want to unbind scroll on resize and make the div always fixed  in small screen http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0kkx9tsb/14/

Comment: This didn't solved it either. My solution is in the answer below. Thanks for your effort!